# Using props in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im building an app with data from an api and i want to include the users latitude and longitude in the app.

My app is in two files: `app.js` and `main.js`

In `app.js` i render the component like this:

```
render(<Main source="https://api.darksky.net/forecast/apikey/latitude,longitude?units=auto"/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

The latitude and longitude is currently hardcoded in the component source, and i want to make these dynamic.

In my `main.js` the component uses the api like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
 this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.source, function (result) {
  this.setState({
    daily: result.daily.data,
    hourly: result.hourly.data
  });
 }.bind(this));
}
```

Im able to fetch the users location using HTML geolocation - which i guess i should store in the constructor or componentWillMount, but i need a way to send the variable into the `app.js` file in the source for the main component - i guess i should use props like for the source but i dont know how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be a good approach to pass the longitude and latitude into your component as props and to assemble the URL inside the component:

```
render(<Main longitude={longitude} latitude={latitude} />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

---

```
componentDidMount() {
    const url = `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/apikey/${this.props.latitude},${this.props.longitude}?units=auto`;
    this.serverRequest = $.get(url, function (result) {
        this.setState({
            daily: result.daily.data,
            hourly: result.hourly.data
        });
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: You need to first get the coordinates which is an asynchronous action.

Comment: This works, thanks! :) Is it possible to place the geolocation inside the componentDidMount to fetch the latitude and longitude here as well?

Comment: Of course, you can simply make your call in `componentDidMount` of your  component and start the API call of the geolocation callback.

Answer (score 1):

Since HTML geolocation is async the `render()` call could go into the geolocation success callback:

```
if (navigator.geolocation){

  function success(position) {
    var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Main lat={ latitude } lon={ longitude } />, document.getElementById('container')
    );
  };

  function error() {
    console.log( 'geolocation error' )
  };


  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/62204/

A more advanced example would be a Higher Order Component that does the geolocation and passes coordinates to the wrapped component. The wrapped component should then check for coordinates in `componentWillReceiveProps` method and do the AJAX request once the props are non-null:

```
var GeoComponent = Component => React.createClass({
    getInitialState(){
        return {
            lat : null, 
            lon : null
        }
    },

    componentDidMount(){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.setCoordinates, err => console.log( err ));
    },

    setCoordinates( position ){
        this.setState({
            lat : position.coords.latitude,
            lon : position.coords.longitude
        })
    },

    render(){
        return <Component lat={ this.state.lat } lon={ this.state.lon } { ...this.props } />;
    }
});

var Main = React.createClass({
    componentWillReceiveProps( nextProps ){
        if( nextProps.lat && nextProps.lon ){
            console.log( 'received coords!' );
            /*
              this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.source, function (result) {
              this.setState({
              daily: result.daily.data,
              hourly: result.hourly.data
              });
              }.bind(this));
            */
        }
    },

    render(){
        return <div>Latitude: { this.props.lat }, Longitude: { this.props.lon }</div>;
    }

});


ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(GeoComponent(Main )),
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/62205/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are right that i need to place the render methode inside the callback to make it work. However i think it feels a bit slow, since i have to wait for the geolocation to proc - but i guess thats the only way?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken then what you want to achieve is to have access to the geolocation info in `app.js`, don't you? Then why don't you just fetch user geolocation inside `app.js` and pass it into `Main`? The code would be something like

app.js

```
let geo = null;
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
  geo = pos;

  render(<Main source={`https://api.darksky.net/forecast/apikey/${geo.coords.latitude},${geo.coords.longitude}?units=auto`}/>, document.getElementById('app'));

  // Below use user's geolocation info as you wish
});
```

---

Or if you want to render some placeholder before getting the user's geolocation info then you may let the Main component do most of the things and pass a callback to Main to update the geolocation info to app.js

app.js

```
render(<Main updateGeolocation={geo => { /* do stuffs with geo */ }} />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

main.js

```
componentDidMount() {
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
  this.serverRequest = $.get(`https://api.darksky.net/forecast/apikey/${pos.coords.latitude},${pos.coords.longitude}?units=auto`, function (result) {
   this.setState({
     daily: result.daily.data,
     hourly: result.hourly.data
   });
  }.bind(this));

  this.props.updateGeolocation(pos);
 }
}
```